# Julia pkg> add results in "no known versions" errors for "Flux" and "Plots"

Tags: julia, flux.jl, julia-plots, julia-pkg

I am using Julia version 1.5.1 on a Win10 operating system. Trying to add Plots and Flux results in the errors listed below:

```
(@v1.5) pkg> add Plots
  Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package Contour [d38c429a]:
 Contour [d38c429a] log:
 ├─Contour [d38c429a] has no known versions!
 └─found to have no compatible versions left with Plots [91a5bcdd]
   └─Plots [91a5bcdd] log:
     ├─possible versions are: [0.12.1-0.12.4, 0.13.0-0.13.1, 0.14.0-0.14.2, 0.15.0-0.15.1, 0.16.0, 0.17.0-0.17.4, 0.18.0, 0.19.0-0.19.3, 0.20.0-0.20.6, 0.21.0, 0.22.0-0.22.5, 0.23.0-0.23.2, 0.24.0, 0.25.0-0.25.3, 0.26.0-0.26.3, 0.27.0-0.27.1, 0.28.0-0.28.4, 0.29.0-0.29.9, 1.0.0-1.0.14, 1.1.0-1.1.4, 1.2.0-1.2.6, 1.3.0-1.3.7, 1.4.0-1.4.4, 1.5.0-1.5.9, 1.6.0-1.6.3] or uninstalled
     └─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions [0.12.1-0.12.4, 0.13.0-0.13.1, 0.14.0-0.14.2, 0.15.0-0.15.1, 0.16.0, 0.17.0-0.17.4, 0.18.0, 0.19.0-0.19.3, 0.20.0-0.20.6, 0.21.0, 0.22.0-0.22.5, 0.23.0-0.23.2, 0.24.0, 0.25.0-0.25.3, 0.26.0-0.26.3, 0.27.0-0.27.1, 0.28.0-0.28.4, 0.29.0-0.29.9, 1.0.0-1.0.14, 1.1.0-1.1.4, 1.2.0-1.2.6, 1.3.0-1.3.7, 1.4.0-1.4.4, 1.5.0-1.5.9, 1.6.0-1.6.3]
```

```
(@v1.5) pkg> add Flux
  Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package Flux [587475ba]:
 Flux [587475ba] log:
 ├─Flux [587475ba] has no known versions!
 └─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement — no versions left
```

I have tried the `pkg> update` and `pkg> gc` commands as well, but that did not identify any changes.

The `pkg> status` yields

```
(@v1.5) pkg> status
Status `~\.julia\environments\v1.5\Project.toml`
  [c3e4b0f8] Pluto v0.11.14
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried running `resolve` or `build`? I would also suggest removing Pluto, adding Plots and FLux, and then re-adding Pluto.

Comment: You either have no registry or a corrupt one. Try to delete `~/.julia/registries/General` and try again.

Comment: @fredrikekre This solved the issue for me. Thank you!